# Issue in making a struct Codable

Tags: ios, swift, codable, decodable, encodable

I have `Application` protocol with 2 variables. And I have `component` struct that has a variable, which confirms to `Application` protocol. I need to save this `struct` in disk . So I'm  confirming it to `Codable` protocol. While doing so I'm getting an error like this ,

> "Protocol type 'Application' cannot conform to 'Decodable' because only concrete types can conform to protocols"

Here is my code,

```
public protocol Application {
     var name : String {get}
     var ownerName : String {get}
}

public struct component : Codable {
     let application : Application
     private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
           case application
       }

public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        application = try values.decode(Application.self, forKey: .application)
    }

 public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(application, forKey: .application)
    }
 }
```

I'm new to swift so sorry if I'm missing something very obvious. Im not able to fix this and  I need some help in right direction. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you paste your json too?

Comment: "only concrete types can conform to protocols" - so use concrete types here.

Comment: `Application` is not `Codable` so `component` can’t be.

Comment: why you want to use protocol ? instead of struct ?

Comment: Application needs to be a struct that conforms to codable or change it to some struct that does.

Comment: I don't have a json. I have json in some other format and im parsing and constructing model in above mentioned form. I wanna share this model with my extension so for that im saving this model in disk.

Comment: Is there any way to make my `component` struct confirm to 'Codable' without making `Application` as struct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How you address this strongly depends on the problem you're solving.

If you want to store and load exactly these two keys in JSON, then Application should be a struct (as jawadAli notes).

If you mean to store more information, but a given Component is tied to exactly one type of Application, then you want Component to be generic:

```
public struct Component<App: Application & Codable> : Codable {
     let application : App
     ...
}
```

Note the addition of `& Codable`. If all things that conform to Application should be Codable, then you can make that a requirement of `Application`:

```
public protocol Application: Codable {
     var name : String {get}
     var ownerName : String {get}
}
```

It is important to understand that this does not make Application conform to Codable. It means that in order to conform to Application, a type must also conform to Codable. It is never possible to decode an abstract type (i.e. a protocol).

If you mean to store more information, but a given Component doesn't actually know what kind of Application it holds, then this is a more complicated problem (and often over-complicated and should be rethought; if you find you're using a lot of `as?` tests, then you should almost certainly redesign). If that's your problem, you should explain a bit more what problem you're solving, and we can discuss how to solve it. (It generally requires some kind of dynamic type registration system, and a JSON format that supports metadata about types. Or you can switch to NSCoder and not use JSON.)

Comment: Thanks man. I really appreciate your detailed answer. I fixed my issue by creating an intermediary struct and saving it in disk.

Answer (score 2):

Use Struct that is confirming to codable instead of protocol will solve the issue

```
public struct Application : Codable {
     var name : String
     var ownerName : String
}
```